# is there a way to ignore part of a datetime string when using DateTime.TryParseExact?

Tags: c#, .net

My datetime string looks like this

```
19430403000000-0400
```

But I only care about the values before the dash (i know its UTC offset, but I don't require that offset value)

So I want to use DateTime.TryParseExact if possible since I have a class that already implements it where the user passes the datetime format as string

So for this I want something like

```
"yyyyMMddhhmmss-####"
```

where the user can ignore parts of the string format

Is that possible?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just remove that part before trying to parse it to a DateTime?

Comment: @Stijn well that's a good idea that I hadn't thought of, but what I need to accomplish is to randomize the date and put it back in its original format. I guess it just involves a bit more coding to do it myself

Comment: Randomize the date? In what way? Also, if the position of "-" is constant, you can use the `String.Substring()` method; If it's not constant, `String.IndexOf('-')` to find its place and then use `String.Substring()`. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: @AsadAli randomize the date components (year, month, day) and return it back with those new values but in the original format.  I suppose I could remove the UTC offset by substring at the dash, but I would have to put it back again.  That might be an option, but I have to test it on various date time formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I still have to specify the entire format, I just have to use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime.  Seems to parse it alright.

```
string date8 = "19430403000000-0400";

        DateTimeOffset result2;
        bool parsed = DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(date8, "yyyyMMddhhmmss zzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces,
                               out result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "19430403000000-0400";
string output = str.Split("-")[0];
```